In Structurizr, create links between landscape view to all software system context views
In Structurizr you can create a landscape view showing the relation between all your software systems. The documentation states that:

The workspace could be configured so that double-clicking software system A in the system landscape diagram takes you workspace 1, where the details of that software system can be found.

How to enable that for more software systems than just a single one?
Structurizer suggests to have a separate workspace.dsl file per software system which extends from the overall landscape workspace defintion.
If I do that and create views based on the extending workspace, I end up with a landscape view containing only a single link on the software system I extended with and no other software system is linked.
On the other hand, I can keep all my workspace definitions in a single file, which results in a landscape view with many links, but this is the opposite of what the documentation suggests and the inspect command keeps complaining about there should only be 1 software system defined per workspace file.
Is there some DSL definition available which I am overlooking, or is there a missmatch between suggested best practices and functionality?
Example DSLs:

system-landscape.dsl

workspace {

    configuration {
        scope landscape
    }


    model {
        a = softwareSystem A
        b = softwareSystem B

        a -> b "request API" "https"
    }

    views {
        systemLandscape landscape {
            include *
            autolayout lr
        }
    }
}



software system A workspace.dsl:

workspace extends system-landscape.dsl {

    configuration {
        scope softwareSystem
    }

    model {
        !extend a {
            a-server = container "Server"
            a-db = container "Database"

            a-server -> a-db "read/write"
        }
    }

    views {
        systemContext a aSystemContextView {
            include *
            autolayout lr
        }

        container a aContainerView {
            include *
            autolayout lr
        }
    }
}


software system B workspace.dsl:

workspace extends system-landscape.dsl {

    configuration {
        scope softwareSystem
    }

    model {
        !extend b {
            b-server = container "Server"
            b-db = container "Database"

            b-server -> b-db "read/write"
        }
    }

    views {
        systemContext b bSystemContextView {
            include *
            autolayout lr
        }

        container b bContainerView {
            include *
            autolayout lr
        }
    }
}


In order to add custom link for the element you will have to add url to it.
Here is how you can do it with DSL, haven't tested myself as I am working with Java version.
And here is how you can do it with Java (void com.structurizr.model.ModelItem.setUrl(String url) method). For Java I am sure it works as I have used it myself.

although not exactly what I hoped for, it does the job. And indeed I overlooked this option..
